# Build error : Cannot find getter for field

Tags: android-room, androidx, build-error

I am trying to create an entity for RoomDB through android application. I am using AndroidX.
Could create the entity without any runtime error. But gives a compile time error for the entity with returning **Cannot find getter for field** error.

Here is the entity,

```java
    package com.example.model;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.room.Entity;
    import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    @Entity
    public class ItemMaster implements Serializable {


        @PrimaryKey
        @NonNull
        private String itemCode;
        private String mCode;
        private String invItem;
        private Boolean act;
        private String fb;
        private String text_;
        private String dept;
        private String cat;
        private String textSht;
        private String depNo;
        private String subDep;
        private String locked;
        private String mec;
        private String taxFlag;
        private Integer kitchPno;
        private String kitchPrn;
        private String spec;
        private Integer slips;
        private Boolean allIncl;
        private Double priceUsd;
        private Double exchRate;
        private Double price1Nw;
        private Double price1Nt;
        private Double price1;
        private Double price2Nw;
        private Double price2Nt;
        private Double price2;
        private Double price3Nw;
        private Double price3Nt;
        private Double price3;
        private Double price4Nw;
        private Double price4Nt;
        private Double price4;
        private Double price5Nw;
        private Double price5Nt;
        private Double price5;
        private Double price6Nw;
        private Double price6Nt;
        private Double price6;
        private Double price7Nw;
        private Double price7Nt;
        private Double price7;
        private Double price8Nw;
        private Double price8Nt;
        private Double price8;
        private Double price9Nw;
        private Double price9Nt;
        private Double price9;
        private Double price10Nw;
        private Double price10Nt;
        private Double price10;
        private String posgF2;
        private Double costP;
        private String posgFlag;
        private String openItem;
        private String happyFlag;
        private Integer oneToOne;
        private Double cnt;
        private Double tod;
        private Double mtd;
        private Double ytd;
        private Double daySale;
        private Double opnStk;
        private Double opnStk2;
        private Double opnStk3;
        private Double prvOpnStk;
        private Double prvOpnBev;
        private Double opnBev;
        private Double bevIn;
        private Double bevOut;
        private Double daySaleBev;
        private Double wastage;
        private String itRem;
        private String add1;
        private String add2;
        private String add3;
        private String add4;
        private Integer id_;
        private Integer toucol;

        @NonNull
        public String getItemCode() {
            return itemCode;
        }

        public void setItemCode(@NonNull String itemCode) {
            this.itemCode = itemCode;
        }

        public String getmCode() {
            return mCode;
        }

        public void setmCode(String mCode) {
            this.mCode = mCode;
        }

        public String getInvItem() {
            return invItem;
        }

        public void setInvItem(String invItem) {
            this.invItem = invItem;
        }

        public Boolean getAct() {
            return act;
        }

        public void setAct(Boolean act) {
            this.act = act;
        }

        public String getFb() {
            return fb;
        }

        public void setFb(String fb) {
            this.fb = fb;
        }

        public String getDept() {
            return dept;
        }

        public void setDept(String dept) {
            this.dept = dept;
        }

        public String getCat() {
            return cat;
        }

        public void setCat(String cat) {
            this.cat = cat;
        }

        public String getTextSht() {
            return textSht;
        }

        public void setTextSht(String textSht) {
            this.textSht = textSht;
        }

        public String getDepNo() {
            return depNo;
        }

        public void setDepNo(String depNo) {
            this.depNo = depNo;
        }

        public String getSubDep() {
            return subDep;
        }

        public void setSubDep(String subDep) {
            this.subDep = subDep;
        }

        public String getLocked() {
            return locked;
        }

        public void setLocked(String locked) {
            this.locked = locked;
        }

        public String getMec() {
            return mec;
        }

        public void setMec(String mec) {
            this.mec = mec;
        }

        public String getTaxFlag() {
            return taxFlag;
        }

        public void setTaxFlag(String taxFlag) {
            this.taxFlag = taxFlag;
        }

        public Integer getKitchPno() {
            return kitchPno;
        }

        public void setKitchPno(Integer kitchPno) {
            this.kitchPno = kitchPno;
        }

        public String getKitchPrn() {
            return kitchPrn;
        }

        public void setKitchPrn(String kitchPrn) {
            this.kitchPrn = kitchPrn;
        }

        public String getSpec() {
            return spec;
        }

        public void setSpec(String spec) {
            this.spec = spec;
        }

        public Integer getSlips() {
            return slips;
        }

        public void setSlips(Integer slips) {
            this.slips = slips;
        }

        public Boolean getAllIncl() {
            return allIncl;
        }

        public void setAllIncl(Boolean allIncl) {
            this.allIncl = allIncl;
        }

        public Double getPriceUsd() {
            return priceUsd;
        }

        public void setPriceUsd(Double priceUsd) {
            this.priceUsd = priceUsd;
        }

        public Double getExchRate() {
            return exchRate;
        }

        public void setExchRate(Double exchRate) {
            this.exchRate = exchRate;
        }

        public Double getPrice1Nw() {
            return price1Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice1Nw(Double price1Nw) {
            this.price1Nw = price1Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice1Nt() {
            return price1Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice1Nt(Double price1Nt) {
            this.price1Nt = price1Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice1() {
            return price1;
        }

        public void setPrice1(Double price1) {
            this.price1 = price1;
        }

        public Double getPrice2Nw() {
            return price2Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice2Nw(Double price2Nw) {
            this.price2Nw = price2Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice2Nt() {
            return price2Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice2Nt(Double price2Nt) {
            this.price2Nt = price2Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice2() {
            return price2;
        }

        public void setPrice2(Double price2) {
            this.price2 = price2;
        }

        public Double getPrice3Nw() {
            return price3Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice3Nw(Double price3Nw) {
            this.price3Nw = price3Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice3Nt() {
            return price3Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice3Nt(Double price3Nt) {
            this.price3Nt = price3Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice3() {
            return price3;
        }

        public void setPrice3(Double price3) {
            this.price3 = price3;
        }

        public Double getPrice4Nw() {
            return price4Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice4Nw(Double price4Nw) {
            this.price4Nw = price4Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice4Nt() {
            return price4Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice4Nt(Double price4Nt) {
            this.price4Nt = price4Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice4() {
            return price4;
        }

        public void setPrice4(Double price4) {
            this.price4 = price4;
        }

        public Double getPrice5Nw() {
            return price5Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice5Nw(Double price5Nw) {
            this.price5Nw = price5Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice5Nt() {
            return price5Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice5Nt(Double price5Nt) {
            this.price5Nt = price5Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice5() {
            return price5;
        }

        public void setPrice5(Double price5) {
            this.price5 = price5;
        }

        public Double getPrice6Nw() {
            return price6Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice6Nw(Double price6Nw) {
            this.price6Nw = price6Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice6Nt() {
            return price6Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice6Nt(Double price6Nt) {
            this.price6Nt = price6Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice6() {
            return price6;
        }

        public void setPrice6(Double price6) {
            this.price6 = price6;
        }

        public Double getPrice7Nw() {
            return price7Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice7Nw(Double price7Nw) {
            this.price7Nw = price7Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice7Nt() {
            return price7Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice7Nt(Double price7Nt) {
            this.price7Nt = price7Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice7() {
            return price7;
        }

        public void setPrice7(Double price7) {
            this.price7 = price7;
        }

        public Double getPrice8Nw() {
            return price8Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice8Nw(Double price8Nw) {
            this.price8Nw = price8Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice8Nt() {
            return price8Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice8Nt(Double price8Nt) {
            this.price8Nt = price8Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice8() {
            return price8;
        }

        public void setPrice8(Double price8) {
            this.price8 = price8;
        }

        public Double getPrice9Nw() {
            return price9Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice9Nw(Double price9Nw) {
            this.price9Nw = price9Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice9Nt() {
            return price9Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice9Nt(Double price9Nt) {
            this.price9Nt = price9Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice9() {
            return price9;
        }

        public void setPrice9(Double price9) {
            this.price9 = price9;
        }

        public Double getPrice10Nw() {
            return price10Nw;
        }

        public void setPrice10Nw(Double price10Nw) {
            this.price10Nw = price10Nw;
        }

        public Double getPrice10Nt() {
            return price10Nt;
        }

        public void setPrice10Nt(Double price10Nt) {
            this.price10Nt = price10Nt;
        }

        public Double getPrice10() {
            return price10;
        }

        public void setPrice10(Double price10) {
            this.price10 = price10;
        }

        public String getPosgF2() {
            return posgF2;
        }

        public void setPosgF2(String posgF2) {
            this.posgF2 = posgF2;
        }

        public Double getCostP() {
            return costP;
        }

        public void setCostP(Double costP) {
            this.costP = costP;
        }

        public String getPosgFlag() {
            return posgFlag;
        }

        public void setPosgFlag(String posgFlag) {
            this.posgFlag = posgFlag;
        }

        public String getOpenItem() {
            return openItem;
        }

        public void setOpenItem(String openItem) {
            this.openItem = openItem;
        }

        public String getHappyFlag() {
            return happyFlag;
        }

        public void setHappyFlag(String happyFlag) {
            this.happyFlag = happyFlag;
        }

        public Integer getOneToOne() {
            return oneToOne;
        }

        public void setOneToOne(Integer oneToOne) {
            this.oneToOne = oneToOne;
        }

        public Double getCnt() {
            return cnt;
        }

        public void setCnt(Double cnt) {
            this.cnt = cnt;
        }

        public Double getTod() {
            return tod;
        }

        public void setTod(Double tod) {
            this.tod = tod;
        }

        public Double getMtd() {
            return mtd;
        }

        public void setMtd(Double mtd) {
            this.mtd = mtd;
        }

        public Double getYtd() {
            return ytd;
        }

        public void setYtd(Double ytd) {
            this.ytd = ytd;
        }

        public Double getDaySale() {
            return daySale;
        }

        public void setDaySale(Double daySale) {
            this.daySale = daySale;
        }

        public Double getOpnStk() {
            return opnStk;
        }

        public void setOpnStk(Double opnStk) {
            this.opnStk = opnStk;
        }

        public Double getOpnStk2() {
            return opnStk2;
        }

        public void setOpnStk2(Double opnStk2) {
            this.opnStk2 = opnStk2;
        }

        public Double getOpnStk3() {
            return opnStk3;
        }

        public void setOpnStk3(Double opnStk3) {
            this.opnStk3 = opnStk3;
        }

        public Double getPrvOpnStk() {
            return prvOpnStk;
        }

        public void setPrvOpnStk(Double prvOpnStk) {
            this.prvOpnStk = prvOpnStk;
        }

        public Double getPrvOpnBev() {
            return prvOpnBev;
        }

        public void setPrvOpnBev(Double prvOpnBev) {
            this.prvOpnBev = prvOpnBev;
        }

        public Double getOpnBev() {
            return opnBev;
        }

        public void setOpnBev(Double opnBev) {
            this.opnBev = opnBev;
        }

        public Double getBevIn() {
            return bevIn;
        }

        public void setBevIn(Double bevIn) {
            this.bevIn = bevIn;
        }

        public Double getBevOut() {
            return bevOut;
        }

        public void setBevOut(Double bevOut) {
            this.bevOut = bevOut;
        }

        public Double getDaySaleBev() {
            return daySaleBev;
        }

        public void setDaySaleBev(Double daySaleBev) {
            this.daySaleBev = daySaleBev;
        }

        public Double getWastage() {
            return wastage;
        }

        public void setWastage(Double wastage) {
            this.wastage = wastage;
        }

        public String getItRem() {
            return itRem;
        }

        public void setItRem(String itRem) {
            this.itRem = itRem;
        }

        public String getAdd1() {
            return add1;
        }

        public void setAdd1(String add1) {
            this.add1 = add1;
        }

        public String getAdd2() {
            return add2;
        }

        public void setAdd2(String add2) {
            this.add2 = add2;
        }

        public String getAdd3() {
            return add3;
        }

        public void setAdd3(String add3) {
            this.add3 = add3;
        }

        public String getAdd4() {
            return add4;
        }

        public void setAdd4(String add4) {
            this.add4 = add4;
        }
        public Integer getToucol() {
            return toucol;
        }

        public void setToucol(Integer toucol) {
            this.toucol = toucol;
        }

        public String getText_() {
            return text_;
        }

        public void setText_(String text_) {
            this.text_ = text_;
        }

        public Integer getId_() {
            return id_;
        }

        public void setId_(Integer id_) {
            this.id_ = id_;
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way to solve this error.

Thanks in-advance.

Comment: Where exactly is the error? Which field is it complaining does not have a getter?

Comment: Try renaming `getmCode()` to `getMCode()`

Comment: @MattU : That is the problem android studio just only showing the error. not showing the relevant line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should name with `@ColumnInfo(name = "yourcolumn")` annotation in order to avoid such errors.

in your case `

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "mcode")
public String mCode;
```